# Download generated file with jQuery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, http-post

I need to download file from javascript. I send json with $.post, Rails server generates xls file and sends it back with send_data. Response has nex headers:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="preflist.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/ms-excel
```

How can I download this file after post request?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you need to trigger normal browser file download after posting data to the server.

There are two ways of doing this:

1. After success of post you redirect your browser to an URL where the posted file is located
2. If the only source of the file is on the response of the post you will have to use the FileReader API, though that is not supported by all browsers. You combine reading the file from the result of the post with readAsDataURL(). The result of this is something you can combine with a hyperlink and the download attribute:

   `<a href="{{result_of_the_readAsDataURL}}" download="{{nameOfFile}}"></a>`

Then use javascript or jQuery to click that hyperlink.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

Hope this helps!